# Check for value in Observable

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm just learning Typescript/nestjs, so the whole subscribe concept is still a little cloudy.

I'm trying to check to see wether or not a passed ID exists in our db, if it does then I know the person is an agent otherwise they're a customer.  Currently, it's returning true for whatever id.

```
getAgent(agentId: number) {
    const agent$ = from(
        this.agentRepository.findAll({
            attributes: ['agentId'],
            where: {
                agentId: {
                    [Op.eq]: agentId
                }
            }
        })
    );
    return agent$;
}
```

returns from the endpoint.

```
[
  {
    "agentId": 1234567890
  }
]
```

where I'm using it is on an if statement

```
if (event.author_id === -1) {
    update_actor = 'system';
    source_status = 0;
} else if (this.getAgent(event.author_id)) {
  console.log(this.getAgent(event.author_id));

  update_actor = 'agent';
} else {
update_actor = 'customer';
source_status = 1;
}
```

If I add subscribe(), it returns from the endpoint:

```
   {
    "closed": false,
    "_parentage": null,
    "_finalizers": null,
    "isStopped": false,
    "destination": {
    "partialObserver": {}
    }
  }
```

If I use it with getValue I get
Property 'getValue' does not exist on type 'Observable<Agent[]>'.

I also tried:

```
    const foundAgentId = agent.pipe(
      map(async (agent) => agent.map(({ agentId }) => agentId))
   );
```

Which returns from hitting the it through an endpoint.

```
  [ 1234567890 ]
```

or [] if there is no record for that id.

So my first question, how do I have it return a true/false?

and my second question, if I returned a full list of agents how could I do something like
agentList.includes(123456780) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to use an async value synchronously, that won't work at all

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out for about a day, so been looking at code from other Stack questions. grasping at straws

Comment: To not rework your code completely I guess it would be best to just return the promise and await it in the caller. But you have to cascade the async keyword then.

Comment: moving this code out of PHP anyway so not opposed to recoding.  I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

thanks @MoxxiManagarm  ended up doing this

```
    const fetchAgentList = await this.getAgents();
    const agentList = fetchAgentList.map((agent) => {
        return agent.agentId;
    });
```